# CDF of Transform of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $U$ follow a uniform distribution on the interval $(0, 2\pi)$

Find the cumulative distribution function of $\sin^2(U) + \cos^2(U)$

Can you simplify this using the pythagorean identity?

Otherwise, how can I do this?

Comment: Hmmm... $\sin^2+ \cos^2$... Does this ring a bell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

$P(\sin^2(U)+\cos^2(U)\le u)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}0&\mbox{if}&u<1\\1&\mbox{if}&u\ge 1\end{array}\right.$